# Image align next to the text

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

i am in a pinch. I was trying my best to get my training website block look like this: http://prntscr.com/4cd4gm But i have no idea anymore how to align those two. I can align pictures, but when it comes to text and paragraph, i fail. I cant make them align to each other, paragraph never goes up.. I tried to do it with columns too, but failed. I think that its something easy and i am overthinking it. Could someone help me out ? Thank you! Here's the code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbhoB

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> xxx</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="headerbg">
        <h1>Welcome to the homepage</h1>
    </div><!-- END HEADERBG -->
    <div class="first-panel">

        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Fy3HxDt.png" class="img1" alt="IPAD">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HnnetnV.png"   class="img2" alt="IPHONE">
        <div class="main-text-heading">
    <h2 class="main-heading first-panel-heading">Flexible</h2>
    <p class="main-text first-panel-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- END FIRST PANEL -->
    <div class="second-panel">
        <!-- <img src="img/clock-cloud.png" alt="Clock and Cloud"> -->
    <h2 class="main-heading">Fast</h2>
    <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
    </div><!-- END SECOND PANEL -->
    </div><!-- END GRID -->
</body>
</html>
```

and css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

/* --------------- TEXT ---------------*/

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.875em; /* 30/16=1.975em */
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-heading {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em; /* 24/16 = 1.5 em */
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #8b8b8b;
}

.main-text {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #8b8b8b;

}

/* --------------- FIXING WHITE SPACES -- */
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*  -------------- HEADER --------------- */

.headerbg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #04bf75;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25.5em; /* 408/16 */
    padding-left: 3em; /* 1200/400 */
    display: block;

}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 204px; /* 408/2 */
    margin-top: -0.9375em;/* 30/2; 15/16 */
}

/* --------------- MAIN SECTION ---------- */

/* --------------- FIRST PANEL ----------- */


.first-panel {

    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25.5em 3em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;



}

img {
    float: left;
}


.first-panel-heading {

}

.first-panel-text {



}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wferd)

what i did was put the images into a separate `div` and the info on the right in a separate `div`. Then I added `disaply: inline-block` to both so that they stay in the same line. NexT I gave the `.image` div a width of 33% and th `.info` div a width of 66% and finally vertically aligning the info div to top

Hope this helps.

Edit: i changed the wrapper width to 1000px so that it is closer to what i see in the screenshot.

Comment: But now the header dissapeared :X

Answer (score 0):

***HTML FILE***

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> xxx</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="headerbg">
        <h1>Welcome to the homepage</h1>
    </div><!-- END HEADERBG -->
    <div class="first-panel">

        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Fy3HxDt.png" class="img1" alt="IPAD" style="left: 10%;top: 77%;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HnnetnV.png"   class="img2" alt="IPHONE" style="top: 95%; left: 7%;">
        <div class="main-text-heading" style="position: absolute; left: 32%; top: 81%; text-align: justify; width: 50%;"">
    <h2 class="main-heading first-panel-heading">Flexible</h2>
    <p class="main-text first-panel-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- END FIRST PANEL -->

    </div><!-- END GRID -->
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS***

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

/* --------------- TEXT ---------------*/

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.875em; /* 30/16=1.975em */
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-heading {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5em; /* 24/16 = 1.5 em */
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #8b8b8b;
}

.main-text {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #8b8b8b;

}

/* --------------- FIXING WHITE SPACES -- */
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*  -------------- HEADER --------------- */

.headerbg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #04bf75;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25.5em; /* 408/16 */
    padding-left: 3em; /* 1200/400 */
    display: block;

}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 204px; /* 408/2 */
    margin-top: -0.9375em;/* 30/2; 15/16 */
}

/* --------------- MAIN SECTION ---------- */

/* --------------- FIRST PANEL ----------- */


.first-panel {

    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25.5em 3em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;



}

img {
    position: absolute;
}


.first-panel-heading {
    text-align: center;

}

.first-panel-text {



}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    clear: both;
}
```

***Kindly get back for any clarifications ...***

***Note : Change the Top and Left styles according to your requirement and resolutions***

Answer (score 0):

Guess it´s more something like that.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJHak)

Created a wrapper arround Pic´s and both text´s.
Created an extra div for images.
Floating like

```
.first-panel {
float:left;
width:35%;
}

.images {
float:left;
width:30%;
}

.second-panel {
float:right;
width:35%;
}
```

Done

Greetings.